# Xamarin MvvmCross call command handler from another viewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have two view models: `ListItemViewModel` and `ListViewModel`. My `ListViewModel` contains many `ListItemViewModel` objects, when I try to delete one item, I'm binding `DeleteCommand` in `ListItemViewModel` like this:

```
public IMvxCommand DeleteCommand => new MvxCommand(DeleteCommandHandler);
```

The problem is that `DeleteCommandHandler` is in `ListViewModel`... How can I call handler from another view model?

**UPDATE 1**

Got the question why do I need this. The reason of my question is that in handler I will need to make an API call which requires dependency injection, but my `ListItemViewModel` must have default empty constructor because of automapper, so all the business logic I want to move to "parent view model" which is `ListViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

Try using messaging services to communicate b/w different viewmodels. In your case, the `DeleteCommandHandler` will trigger in `ListItemViewModel` and then will pass a message to `ListViewModel` sending details of item deleted.

Refer to the [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) on how to implement Messaging.

Comment: It would be nice to solve my problem without messaging :)

Comment: Why can't you have your Handler in ListViewModel?

Comment: my handler is in `ListViewModel`

Comment: Why do you want to call handler from another viewmodel, I mean what is your end expectation?

Comment: Updated my question with the answer to your question